# disable backspace, delete button on radcheckeddropdownlist in winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have  radcheckeddropdownlist , I am entering check boxes dynamically and i am disabling them once the user check and save, but when i press the back and  delete button saved items are deleting , could any one suggest me how to restrict back, delete button radcheckeddropdownlist . Thanks

I have tried key press event.it didn't work kindly help me.
Inside the key press event i have written the if condition as below:

```
   Private Sub radchecksample_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles radchecksample.KeyUp
    If Not (Asc(e.KeyCode) = Keys.Delete Or Asc(e.KeyCode) = Keys.Back) Then  
        e.Handled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The Delete key should not trigger KeyPress only character keys do. Try KeyUp instead.

Comment: i tried but its not working. Thank you.